# Icecast port forwarding not working

Tags: port-forwarding

I have a PC that I'm running icecast server on. I can access my server on my LAN by using 192.168.1.2:8000. In my netgear router I forwarded external port 8000 to 192.168.1.2:8000.

However when I try to access externalip:8000 the connection times out. What could be causing this?

Edit:
I should add I've tried using two different PCs for the server, in two different locations, with two different isps and routers. Both windows computers.

Comment: I see you setup the NAT, did you also create a firewall rule to allow that port open for the interface/public IP address on your firewall?

Comment: I created a rule for the program and the port. Still didn't work so I temporarily completely disabled windows firewall. Still no luck.

Comment: Does your router have a public IP address on its WAN/Internet interface?

Comment: Yes. It's puzzling because rdp works over port forwarding

Answer (score 0):

In my experience a standard home user style router creates a firewall rule when port forwarding is enabled (Not Guaranteed on all routers). Other then that all I can think is does windows running the server have a firewall enabled? if so is external networks allowed. 2) I use Linux personally this may or may not be relevant for windows as well when accessing my external IP address from inside the network I always get timeout errors. Something to do with how internal networks route. Have you tried giving a friend your IP and ask them to test this from another remote location?

Comment: I've been checking it from my smartphone (over mobile data). Thanks for the suggestion though!